# What is the fastest way to see if the values from a 2 dimensional array are present in 3 other two dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array

I have 4 integer two dimensional arrays of the form:

`{{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}`

The first 3(A,B,C) are of size/shape [1000][3] and the 4th(D) [57100][3].

The combination of integers in the 3 elements sub-arrays in A,B,C are all unique, while combinations of integers in the 3 elements sub-arrays in D are not.

What I have to do is to find in what array from A,B or C a sub-array from D is present and do something with it after, depending in which array I find it.

I tried using nested for loops with if statements and check each array one at a time (A->B->C) and break out when I find it but it takes to long.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. What have you tried so far? Some code snippets would be helpful. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade here's [a list of super-secret formatting tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), including `[ask]` which expands to [ask], you can use to simplify commenting.

Comment: @user4581301 ahh, thank you! Learning something new every day. :)

Comment: *I tried using nested for loops with if statements and check each array one at a time* -- Then it's time to learn data structures, i.e. hash tables, tries, etc..  You should have had a suspicion that a naive, brute-force approach is not going to work.  Also, if you got this assignment from one of those "competition coding" websites, the questions there are designed to have easy, but slow solutions.  Then your goal is then for you to do the research and come up with faster solutions.

Comment: Some ideas: (1) Sort A, B and C or convert them to `std::set` to speed up searching. (2) Create `std::map` out of A, B and C where keys are 3-integer tuples and values are elements of an enum indicating which array the tuple belongs to (A, B or C).

Comment: Try putting A,B,C, and D in a hash set as a `std::tuple<int, int, int>`.  Then go through each item in the D hashset to see if it's in A, B, or C.

Comment: @OP *What is the fastest way* -- You mean a "faster" way, not the fastest.  There are slow ways and fast ways.  The "fastest" way requires research, timing tests, and who knows what else to determine what is the "fastest".  If anyone posts an answer, it is not guaranteed to be "fast" enough for your purposes, only that it is faster than the current approach you are taking.  In that, please post code as to your current attempt, so that we have an idea of what you actually tried.

Comment: If you used a `std::set<std::tuple<int,int,int>>` to store the items, then the number of lookups it takes to find an item in one of those arrays with 1000 rows will be a *maximum* of 10 tries.  I am assuming your current approach goes through each element one by one, so the maximum number of attempts will be 1000.  That right there cuts the time down logarithmically.   Now there are 3 arrays, making it a max of 30 lookups using a `std::set`, while yours has a max of 3000 lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by my comments, let's assume your approach is a naive, look at one item at a time in a `for` loop to see if a match is found.

Instead of doing that, another approach is to store the arrays as a `std::set<std::tuple<int, int, int>>` and do a lookup on the sets.  Doing this reduces the time complexity from linear to logarithmic.  For example, a 1000 item set will have at most 10 tests to finally determine if the item exists instead of having to go through all 1000 items.

Here is a somewhat untested example.  Note that the data in the arrays has not been populated (the assumption is that the data has been populated into the arrays):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <set>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using TupleSet = std::set<std::tuple<int, int, int>>;

int A[1000][3];
int B[1000][3];
int C[1000][3];
int D[57100][3];

void printTuple(const std::tuple<int,int,int>& ts)
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(ts) << "," <<
                 std::get<1>(ts) << "," << 
                 std::get<2>(ts) << "\n";
}

// Initialize the tuple set with the 3 column 2D array of items
void initializeTuple(int pArray[][3], int numItems, TupleSet& ts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
        ts.insert({pArray[i][0], pArray[i][1], pArray[i][2]});
}

int main()
{
   // Assume that A, B, C, and D have been filled in with data
   //...
   static constexpr char *arrayName = "ABC";

   // Declare an array of 3 tuple sets that represent A,B,C 
   std::array<TupleSet, 3> allTuples;

   // This is for the "special" D Array
   TupleSet tD;  

   //Store the data in the tuples
   initializeTuple(A, 1000, allTuples[0]);
   initializeTuple(B, 1000, allTuples[1]);
   initializeTuple(C, 1000, allTuples[2]);
   initializeTuple(D, 57100, tD);

   // Now go through each tuple in D to see if it's
   // in A, B, or C
   for (auto& t : tD)
   {
       // print the tuple we're searching for
       printTuple(t);

       // Now see if it's in A, B, or C   
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
       {
           auto iter = allTuples[i].find(t);
           if ( iter != allTuples[i].end() )
           {  
               std::cout << "Found a match in Array " << 
                             arrayName[i] << "\n";
               break;
           }
        }  
     }
  }
```

Note how each 2D array is placed in a tuple set.  Also, since a `std::set` does not store duplicates, the `D` array will have all of its duplicates removed when placed in the tuple set `tD`.  Thus right there, the number of items that `D` represents will be minimized.

However, there are some issues you should be aware of:

1. The initial setup time of the tuples is part of this solution.  However the setup time is done only once.
2. It may be even faster to use a `std::unordered_set`, but that would require you to write a hash function, and I leave that as an exercise to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works. I will also try the other option you told me.